# Blazor EF Core updating a table with multiple joined tables

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I new to Blazor and EF Core. I've created a simple Blazor project which will display a list of employees. I used EF Core to generate the tables in my SQL database. My employee table links with two other tables (`SalaryRanges` and `Departments`).

My model for the employee table is

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public Salary Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

public class Salary
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SalaryRange { get; set; }
}
```

For my `EmployeeService`, I'm using the following to retrieve the data to list all employees:

```
return await _appDbContext.Employees
                          .FromSqlRaw("Select Id, EmployeeName, Gender, City, DepartmentDeptId, Designation, SalaryId 
                                       from Employees")
                          .Include(e => e.Department)
                          .Include(s => s.Salary)
                          .ToListAsync();
```

This works, but I also tried to use EF Core version similar to

```
return await _appDbContext.Employees
                          .Include(c => c.Department)
                          .Include(s => s.Salary)
                          .ToListAsync();
```

My main problem right now is when I try to retrieve a single record.

I've tried the following

```
// EF Core Version with the extra entity tables
Employee employee = await _appDbContext.Employees
                                       .Include(e => e.Department)
                                       .Include(e => e.Salary)
                                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id.Equals(Id));
return employee;
```

And also

// Raw SQL version

```
Employee employee = await _appDbContext.Employees
                                       .FromSqlRaw($"Select Id, EmployeeName, Gender, City, DepartmentDeptId, Designation, SalaryId 
                                                     from Employees 
                                                     where Id = {Id}")
                                       .Include(e => e.Department)
                                       .Include(s => s.Salary)
                                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

return employee;
```

Both of those statements error out with the message

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I'm not sure what I am missing, but I have a combination of EF Core with raw SQL which doesn't help I'm sure.

I tried the raw SQL statement to get the entire list in my `GetAllEmployees` service with this SQL statement which works in SQL Server Management Studio, but not in my Blazor code

```
select 
    e.Id, e.EmployeeName, e.Gender, e.City, 
    d.DepartmentName, e.Designation, s.SalaryRange 
from 
    Employees e, Departments d, SalaryRanges s 
where 
    e.DepartmentDeptId = d.DeptId and e.SalaryId = s.Id
```

This returns the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'DepartmentDeptId' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.BuildIndexMap(IReadOnlyList`1 columnNames, DbDataReader dataReader)

So my question is two fold. How can I use the raw SQL statement in my `GetAllEmployees` and what am I missing in my select a single employee service call with either the EF method or raw SQL method.

Any help would be great.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Just use star, `Select * from Employees`

Comment: Yes using * works for getting all the records, however using * to get a single record while referencing the Id = to the passed in Id does not work.

Comment: Using these two statements to get a single entry yields a null value for the two linked fields              var sqlStatement = "Select * from [Employees] where [Employees].Id = " + Id;
            return await _appDbContext.Employees.FromSqlRaw(sqlStatement).Include(d => d.Department).Include(s => s.Salary).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: I did come up with this last night as was able to pull the data with the correct information.  The only downside now is that I cant convert an ananymous type to my 'Employee' class.

Comment: I was able to make the below code work, however I can't convert the anonymous type to a class.

Comment: var singleEmployee = _appDbContext.Employees.Include(s => s.Department).Include(s => s.Salary)
                .Where(m => m.Id == Id)
                .Select(m => new
                {
                    Id = m.Id,
                    empName = m.EmployeeName,
                    gender = m.Gender,
                    city = m.City,
                    department = m.Department.DepartmentName,
                    desg = m.Designation,
                    salary = m.Salary.SalaryRange
                });

            return (Task<Employee>)singleEmployee;